# Dynamic filter in for loop

Tags: r

I have this simplified nested for loop:

```
for (i in unique(x$A)){
    for(j in unique(x$B)){
        if (sum(x[filter,]$C)==0) next
        ...
    }
}
```

A range is `1:8` and B range is `1:10`

How can I make the filter vary so that, for example, if `i=2` and `j=4` the sum will get the following numbers:

```
[j,i]    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]             
[1,]     ....    ....    ....    ....       1    ....    ....    ....
[2,]     ....    ....    ....       1    ....    ....    ....    ....
[3,]     ....    ....       1    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
[4,]     ....       1    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
[5,]     ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....  
[6,]     ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    .... 
[7,]     ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
[8,]     ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
[10,]    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
```

Example 2 (`j=7` and `i=1`):

```
[j,i]    [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]             
[1,]     ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....       1    ....
[2,]     ....    ....    ....    ....    ....       1    ....    ....
[3,]     ....    ....    ....    ....       1    ....    ....    ....
[4,]     ....    ....    ....       1    ....    ....    ....    ....
[5,]     ....    ....       1    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....  
[6,]     ....       1    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    .... 
[7,]        1    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
[8,]     ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
[10,]    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `sapply`:

```
colindex = seq(i,(i+j-1));
res = sum(sapply(1:j,function(rowindex) m[rowindex,rev(colindex)[rowindex]]))
```

For example for the following matrix `m`:

```
m = matrix(c(1:25),5,5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25

i = 2
j = 3
colindex = seq(i,(i+j-1));
res = sum(sapply(1:j,function(rowindex) m[rowindex,rev(colindex)[rowindex]]))
```

returns the sum of `16+12+8`:

```
[1] 36
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this nested loop below. out is the final result, if you want result of `i = 2`, `j = 4`, simply extract from `out[4, 2]`

```
A = 1:8
B = 1:10
C = matrix(1:80, nrow = 10)
out = matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 8)
for (i in A) {
    for (j in B) {
        k = i
        l = j
        cell = numeric()
        while(l > 0 & k <= 8) {
            cell = c(cell, C[l, k])
            l = l - 1
            k = k + 1
        }
        out[j, i] = sum(cell)
    }
}
out[4, 2]
```

14+23+32+41 = 110 which is `out[4, 2]`